# Select Values/Labels not picked up in Edit record mode. How to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple Ruby on Rails form for a servicerequest model (create / edit). When I create a a new SR, the proper VALUE is stored in the database just fine (value, not the display label), but when I try to retrieve it in the EDIT view, the select dropdown is NOT picking up the existing value/label and defaulting to the first one in the array.

(the priority is NOT a relationship to another model, all contained in a simple array for now).

What am I missing?

NEW & EDIT views (Both the same):

```
<% form_for(@servicerequest, :html => { :class => "newform" }) do |f| %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :priority %><br />
  <%= f.select(:priority, [["Stat", "1"], ["Urgent", "2"], ["Regular", "3"], ["Safety", "4"]], { :prompt => "Choose"})  %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= f.label :priority %>
<%= f.select(:priority, [["Stat", "1"], ["Urgent", "2"], ["Regular", "3"], ["Safety", "4"]], :selected => @servicerequest.priority, :prompt => "Choose") %>
```

Comment: Nope... that threw an error , but this did NOT work either:

<%= f.select(:priority, [["Stat", "1"], ["Urgent", "2"], ["Regular", "3"], ["Safety", "4"]], { :prompt => "Choose", :selected => :priority}) %>

Comment: please add `form_for` line to sources.

Comment: <% form_for(@servicerequest, :html => { :class => "newform" }) do |f| %>

Comment: I suspect it has to do with my manually created array...? I must be missing something simple though, you would think... dang... BTW I am on Rails 2.3 or whatever version that is (not 3)

Answer (score 0):

Another try:

```
<%= f.label :priority %>
<%= f.select(:priority, options_for_select({"Stat" => "1", "Urgent" => "2", "Regular" => "3", "Safety" => "4"}, @servicerequest.priority), :prompt => "Choose") %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I replied in another post. Still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: you can post HTML output, that can help to figure it out

Comment: Highly confusing on how to make it into a code span for a new user, but here it is. Thanks

'<p>
    <label for="servicerequest_priority">Priority</label><br />
    <select id="servicerequest_priority" name="servicerequest[priority]"><option value="1">Stat</option>
<option value="2">Urgent</option>
<option value="3">Regular</option>
<option value="4">Safety</option></select>
  </p>'

Comment: OMG... I wrote to Ryan Bates from railscasts.com... Guess what... The only reason none of these iterations worked (even though we had it right from the get-go) was... THE STRING VS THE INTEGER! The db stored 1s, 2s, and 3s as integers and we were comparing them to strings "1", "2", etc... When the line was changed to: {"Stat" => 1, "Urgent" => 2} it started working magically.... Let me know if you got this and thanks for your help Anatoliy!